# Tick mark not displaying while using html-to-pdf github action

Tags: node.js, github-actions, html-to-pdf

I create an html file using a node js script. It contains a table where I display tick mark based on certain conditions. The code to display the tick mark in the table cell is as follows:

```
<td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>" + "Passed \u2714" + "</td>
```

It displays perfectly fine in html but when I try to convert html to pdf using [html-to-pdf github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/html-to-pdf), it is displaying the pdf without the tick mark.

Code in github action which is converting it:

```
- name: Convert HTML to PDF report
        if: always()
        uses: fifsky/html-to-pdf-action@master
        with:
          htmlFile: results.html
          outputFile: AntmanPerformanceReport.pdf
          pdfOptions: '{"format": "A4", "margin": {"top": "10mm", "left": "10mm", "right": "10mm", "bottom": "10mm"}, "landscape": true, "printBackground": true}'
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 style='color:purple;text-align: center;'>Processing Performance Testing Report</h2><br>
  <table style='width:100%;word-break:break-word;border-radius: 10px;'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style='text-align:left;'>Request Period</th>
        <th style='text-align:left;'>Datadog</th>
        <th style='text-align:left;'>Max Throughput</th>
        <th style='text-align:left;'>Test Length</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-radius: 10px;text-align:left;'>9-1-2023</td>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-radius: 10px;text-align:left;'> <a href='https://app.datadoghq.com/dashboard/u99-4jx-c7g?tpl_var_date=%2A&tpl_var_env=%2A&tpl_var_scenario=%2A&tpl_var_team=%2A&live=true'>K6 Datadog dashboard</a></td>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-radius: 10px;text-align:left;'>1.00 TPS</td>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-radius: 10px;text-align:left;'>0.28030098333333336 mins</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h3 style='color:Silver;font-size:15px;'>Scenario: Full Card Visa</h3>
  <table style='width:100%;word-break:break-word;border: 1px;border-style: ridge;border-color: #DEDEDE border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style='background-color:#CCCCFF;padding: 12px;'>Component</th>
        <th style='background-color:#CCCCFF;padding: 12px;'>Availability SLO</th>
        <th style='background-color:#CCCCFF;padding: 12px;'>Latency SLO</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;padding: 15px;'> Gateway </td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;padding: 15px;'> Prism </td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#f1d138;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>!</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;padding: 15px;'> Vault </td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;padding: 15px;'> Card Processing </td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;padding: 15px;'> Access </td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#f1d138;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>!</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;padding: 15px;'> Harmonia </td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;padding: 15px;'> Routing </td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;background-color:#93C572;border-radius: 10px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;border-bottom: thin solid;border-color:#DEDEDE;border-width: 2px 10px;'>✔</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

PDF:
[image]

How to display the tick mark in the PDF?

Comment: Do you mean the issue is here - ```<td style='font-family:Tahoma;...```. Could you please suggest what font-family should I use instead of Tahoma which would support display of tick mark in the PDF?

Comment: I see, but I m using Mac which I m guessing has a similar issue like you mentioned. But what throws me is that if I use the same node js script to generate a pdf locally say using puppeteer or any such tool, it is able to display the pdf similar to the html I have. The issue arises only while using the github action

Comment: Tried it with ```&#10004;``` -> same issue

Comment: Thanks that worked, feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept it